# Does every mantra in Hinduism have a corresponding god or goddess?

Tags: mantras

In Hinduism there are a large number of mantras.

Does every mantra have its corresponding Devi or Devata?

Comment: Do you mean every mantra is dedicated to particular deity?

Comment: @Paṇḍyā No. I mean presiding deity... In Telugu we say mantra adishtana devatha etc.,